# OAuth2 hasRole always return 401

Tags: java, security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-401

I tried to create Spring Boot App with OAuth2. I created User class defined as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@NotNull
private String username;

@NotNull
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Role> roles;
```

I created user "test" with 2 roles: "USER" and "ADMIN", but when I want to send POST request to "/get" handler I got 401 status. 
My ResourceServerConfig:

```
@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("resource").tokenStore(tokenStore);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/msg/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/get/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig
@Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("trustedClient")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials","password")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
        .scopes("read","write","trust")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000)
        .secret("secret");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/login")
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer())
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer(){
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore(){
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}
```

CustomTokenEnhancer

```
@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    user.setPassword(userDetails.getPassword());
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    for(GrantedAuthority role: userDetails.getAuthorities())
        roles.add(new Role(role.getAuthority()));
    user.setRoles(roles);

    Map<String, Object> additional = new HashMap<>();
    additional.put("user", user);

    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additional);
    return accessToken;
}
```

and last one CustomUserDetails

```
public CustomUserDetails(User byUsername){
    this.username = byUsername.getUsername();
    this.password = byUsername.getPassword();

    List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Role role: byUsername.getRoles())
        auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().toUpperCase()));
    this.authorities = auths;
    System.out.println(this.authorities);
}
```

this last println returns [USER, ADMIN].

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is correct, then by default user roles should have 'ROLE_' prefix. Just add this prefix to users' roles and all should works.

If after this change you still receive 401 status, try to override oauth filter order in application.properties (application.yml):

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
```

This issue related to latest changes in spring oauth since 1.5 version. Please check this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#oauth-2-resource-filter.

Comment: I tried it and it's not working. My user have now ROLE_ADMIN role and still have 401

Comment: Nothing changed, still 401

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/msg/**").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/get/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/msg/**").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/get/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
}
```